# Should I use UTF-8 to send data over the network?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, character-encoding

WinAPI uses UTF-16LE encoding, so if I called some WinAPI function that returns a string, it will return it as UTF-16LE encoded.

So I'm thinking of using UTF-16LE encoding for strings in my program, and when it's time to send the data over the network, I convert it to UTF-8, and on the other side I convert it back to UTF-16LE. This is so there is less amount of data to send.

Is there's a reason why I shouldn't do that?

Comment: It's your program, it can do whatever you want :)

Comment: I might consider UTF-8 for its popularity for interfacing with 3rd party applications but, unless you're sending truly massive qualities of text, I would think it is unlikely to be a bandwidth hog.

Comment: What you are asking is exactly how most modern Internet protocols work.  Native encoding is used for strings in memory, converted to/from UTF-8 when sent over the wire to reduce bandwidth and support cross-platform compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [UTF-8](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, you'll use:

- 1 byte for ASCII chars
- 2 bytes for unicode chars between U+0000 and U+07FF
- more bytes if necesseray

So, if your text is western language, in most case it will probably be shorter in UTF-8 than in UTF-16LE encoding: the western alphabets are [encoded between U-0000 and U-0590](http://unicode-table.com).

On the opposite, if your text is asian, then the UTF8 encoding might inflate significantly your data.  The asian caracter sets are beyond U+7FF and require hence at least 3 bytes

In the [UTF8 everywhere article](http://utf8everywhere.org/) you can find some (basic) statistics about length of text encoding, as well as other arguments supporting the use of UTF8.

One that comes to my mind for networking, is taht UTF8 representation is the same représentation on all platforms, whereas for UTF16 you have the LE and BE, depending on OS and CPU architecure.